# jquery datepicker should not automatically change time value on update minDate or maxDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, datepicker

I use the jquery datepicker in an Angular Application and I noticed a behavior that I would like to prevent.

The application consists of an input field for the date and a select box for a month selection.
If the months in the select box are changed, the minDate of the jquery date picker should be adjusted.

**I tried the following example:**

1. I set the date in the input field to the 24.04.2018
2. I chose October
3. The date of the input field is automatically set to 24.10.2018

**I do not want the content of the Inputs field to be automatically adjusted.**

Here is my git-hub project: https://github.com/annalen/jquery-datepicker

Many thanks for the help

**Solution**
I use the beforeShow and onClose date-picker functions

```js
jQuery(yourElement).datepicker('option', 'beforeShow', function (date) {
  return {
    'minDate': yourMinDate,
    'maxDate': yourMaxDate
  };
});

jQuery(yourElement).datepicker('option', 'onClose', function (date) {
  jQuery(this).datepicker('option', {
    'minDate': null,
    'maxDate': null
  });
});
```

Comment: Please don’t edit the answer into the question. Instead, add an answer to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker updates the date only if the selected one is out of the range.

For example, if the current selected date is 24.04.2018 and you set the minDate to 20.04.2018, nothing will happen.

But if you set it to any date after 24.04.2018, it will get updated. I believe it's normal since its the purpose of setting a minDate.

You can always set yourself manually the input's value: `$('#datepicker').val('20.04.2018')` but I don't think it's a good idea to have something displayed different than the internal datepicker component state (the calendar that will popup will show a different date than the one in the input)

Regards,
Vincent

Comment: Many thanks for your response. It took me a long time to find a solution. In my solution, I use the beforeShow and onClose date-picker functions.